# Проверка на значение в таблице

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($value));
```

так же надо добавить условие, что в этой записи `status` должен быть `!= 0;`

То есть выводим только те , там где `status != 0`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В *Mysql*, как и везде имеются операторы условия такие как `OR` (логическое "ИЛИ") и `AND` (логическое "И"), где с помощью `AND` можно добавить условия почти неограниченного числа раз.

```
sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE `id` = '.$db->quote($value).' AND `status` != 0');
```

описание оператора **[AND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and)**